# How to replace BERT tokenizer special tokens

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, bert-language-model

I am using an AutoTokenizer --> `tokenizer1 = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("vinai/bertweet-base", normalization=True)` which is more complete than the tokenizer of bert-base-uncased. The problem is that when I tokenize some text, this tokenizer has different special tokens:

```
special_tokens={'bos_token': '<s>', 'eos_token': '</s>', 'unk_token': '<unk>', 'sep_token': '</s>', 'pad_token': '<pad>', 'cls_token': '<s>', 'mask_token': '<mask>'})>
```

whereas the bert-base-uncased tokenizer, has these ones:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME, normalization=True)
```

```
special_tokens={'unk_token': '[UNK]', 'sep_token': '[SEP]', 'pad_token': '[PAD]', 'cls_token': '[CLS]', 'mask_token': '[MASK]'})>
```

I would like to replace these special tokens in order to make them fit for bert-base-uncased, so it doesn´t raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly just a string replacement problem, but there are a couple of complications.  Your first set has "bos_token" and "cls_token" both represented by `<s>`, and "eos_token" and "sep_token" both represented by `</s>`.  Your second set doesn't have the BOS and EOS concepts, so if we make the other choices, you could use this:

```
s = s.replace('<s>','[CLS]')  \
     .replace('</s>','[SEP]')  \
     .replace('<unk>','[UNK]')  \
     .replace('<pad>','[PAD]')  \
     .replace('<mask>','[MASK]')
```